# Verificando Diretório (WINDOWS)

Tags: c, c++, windows, diretório, winapi

Como faço para verificar se um diretório existe usando **C++** e **Windows API**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe a função `GetFileAttributesA` que recupera os atributos do sistema
para um diretótio ou arquivo especificado.

Maiores informações  ->  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Aqui uma função simples que faz exatamente o que você quer:

```
bool HYPNOS_DIR_VALIDATE(const std::string& hypnos_dirNAME)
{
  DWORD hypnos_ftyp = GetFileAttributesA(hypnos_dirNAME.c_str());
  if (hypnos_ftyp == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    return false;  // algo de errado com o path

  if (hypnos_ftyp & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    return true;   // É um diretório!

  return false;    // Não é um diretório.
}
```

Comment: O que é o "hypnos"?

Comment: Cara... kkkkk
é só um projeto meu.. :)

Comment: Ok! Boa sorte para o teu projecto. Diverte-te!

Comment: Hahaha, Obrigado!